# My check style plugin in eclipse doesn't showcase a warning for hard coded value for string

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have configured check style plugin in eclipse juno.

I have a following snippet in my code:

```
    articleView.setResponseType("HTML");
    articleView.setImageFilePrefix(imageURL);
    articleView.setUrlIndicator("Y");
```

In above code , I want to make checkstyle plugin to check is there any hard coded values or not like "HTML"

I am using built in sun check style xml file.

I have used following check style plugin version for eclipse juno :
 "net.sf.eclipsecs-updatesite_6.4.0.201503042206-bin.zip"

How can I make my check style plugin to check is there any hard code values  or not mean to say is there, any rule which we can define in check style xml fiel to check hard coded values for string.

Can any one help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Naresh.

Comment: Default checkstyle.xml doesn't come with requirement you have. Did you try writing a new check yourselves? You can do it using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I've copied and modified the existing sun checkstyle configuration and made it default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can do this without check style.

In the Preferences look at 'Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings'. In the 'Code style' section change 'Non-externalized strings' to Warning or Error.

Comment: But I think he requires the configuration to be done in checkstyle xml ,mostly for reporting purposes.